# Why does `log_slow_queries` break `my.cnf`?

Tags: mysql, performance, my.cnf, mysql-slow-query-log

Why can't I use slow_query_log on MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6.4?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
...

## Logging

## *** THESE LOGS WORK JUST FINE ***
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log                     = 1

## *** THESE LOGS BREAK MYSQL ***
#log_slow_queries               = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
#long_query_time                = 5
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Here's the `/var/log/mysql` directory:

```
$ ls -lh
total 100K
-rw-r----- 1 mysql root   47K Nov 22 06:02 error.log
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql root   42K Nov 22 06:05 mysql.log
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    0 Nov 22 06:01 slow.log
```

If I uncomment the log_slow_query lines in the `/etc/my.cnf` I receive the following error:

```
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL.. SUCCESS!
Starting MySQL..... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/server.domain.com.pid).
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looks like MySQL changed the format. Now it's `slow_query_log` not `log_slow_queries`.

This works:

```
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time                 = 5
```

Comment: log_slow_queries was deprecated in MySQL 5.1.29 by slow_query_log. The MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual has more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries